# Sum of perfect powers of n natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, perfect-powers

The perfect power of an integer $n = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r}$ are $p_1^2, p_1^3\cdots p_1^{\alpha_1},p_2^2, p_2^3 \cdots p_2^{\alpha_2},(p_1 p_2)^2, (p_2 p_3)^2\cdots$ similar terms.

Lets define $S(n)$ as the sum of all [perfect powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power) that can be formed from prime factors of n.

Examples:
\begin{align}
  S(9) &= 1+9 = 10  \\
  S(16) &= 1+4+8+16 = 29 \\
  S(36) &= 1+4+9+36 = 50  
\end{align}

Let $$G(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n S(n)$$
is there a short closed form of the sum $G(n)$?

**References**.

1. M. A. Nyblom, [A counting function for the sequence of perfect powers](https://researchbank.rmit.edu.au/eserv/rmit:397/n2006000023.pdf), Austral. Math. Soc. Gaz. 33 (2006), 338–343.
2. R. Jakimczuk, [On the distribution of perfect powers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL14/Jakimczuk3/jakimczuk21.pdf), J. Integer Seq. 14 (2011), Article 11.8.5.
3. similar [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611277/sum-of-perfect-powers)

Comment: This look like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611277/sum-of-perfect-powers)? Please don't post the same question twice.

Comment: @DietrichBurde They are both different. please have a look again.

Comment: So you mean $S(n)$ is the sum of all perfect powers that can be formed with the prime factors of $n$?

Comment: Yes Exactly. @joriki all kinds of perfect powers.